# composition of two uniformly continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are two uniform continuous functions. Which of the following options are correct and why?

1. $f(g(x))$ is uniformly continuous.
2. $f(g(x))$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous.
3. $f(g(x))$ is continuous and bounded.

My attempt:

Every uniformly continuous function maps a Cauchy sequence to a Cauchy sequence. (Here I have a doubt, as the converse may not be true). So if $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence, $\{f(x_n)\}$ and $\{g(f(x_n))\}$ both will be Cauchy sequence. So $g(f(x))$ will be uniformly continuous, i.e. 1 is true.

Composite function of two continuous functions will be continuous. As 1 is true, 2 is false.

$f(x) = x $ is uniformly continuous. $g(x) = \log(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $[1,\infty)$. So $g(f(x)) = \log(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $[1, \infty)$, but not in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Strongly related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/568230/11994.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your suspicion is justified. The argument you give for the validity of 1 is faulty since it only shows the composite preserves Cauchy sequences, but it does not show that the composite is uniformly continuous. Try working directly with the definition of uniform continuity instead to give a direct proof.

You can make things easier with the counter example to 3: Take $f(x)=g(x)=x$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. So 1 is true and 2, 3 are false. Please check the proof for 1. For any $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ $\delta > 0$ s.t. $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - y| < \delta$ because of uniform continuity of $f$. As $g$ is uniformly continuous $|g(f(x)) - g(f(y))| < \epsilon'$ whenever $|f(x) -f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - y| < \delta$. So $g(f(x))$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @IttayWeiss : Sorry  but  I  do  not  understand  what  you  mean  by   the  composite  preserving  cauchy  sequences  but  the  composite  not  being  cauchy. What  is  the  difference  between  the  two? What  is  it  like  a  function  being  cauchy?

Comment: is it possible to say that if $f, g$ are bounded and uniformly continuous then the composition $f \circ g$ is uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 45):

- **Option $(1):$ True:**

  Choose $\epsilon>0.$

  Then $\exists~\delta_1>0$ such that $|x_1-x_2|<\delta_1$$\implies|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon.$

  For above $\delta_1>0~\exists~\delta>0$ such that $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$$\implies|g(x_1)-g(x_2)|<\delta_1.$

  Consequently, $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$$\implies|(f\circ g)(x_1)-(f\circ g)(x_2)|<\epsilon.$
- **Options $(2),~(3):$ Not necessarily true:**

  Take $f(x)=g(x)=x$ on $\mathbb R.$

  Then $f,g$ are uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$

  Note $(f\circ g)(x)=x$ is unbounded and uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$