# Uniform continuity and the sine function.

Tags: uniform-continuity

I'm studying uniform continuity in metric spaces.

> Let ($X$,$d$), ($Y$,$d'$) be metric spaces, $f:X \to Y$.$f$ is said to be uniformily continuous on $X$ iff
>   $$ \forall \epsilon > 0  \; \exists \delta( \epsilon) >0 \; \forall x,x' \in X : d(x,x')< \delta \Rightarrow d'(f(x), f(x')) < \epsilon$$

And as an example we prove that $\sin(x)$ is uniformily continuous  on $\mathbb R$, with the usual metric,  and many more. My question is:

> Is it true that $\sin(f(x))$ is uniformily continuous in some subset of $\mathbb R$ iff f(x) is uniformily continuous on some subset of $\mathbb R$?

I feel that this isn't true, but I don't have any idea how to prove this.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin x$.

Comment: Actually, [composition of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/579375/279404).