# Continuous function with uniformly continuous square.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $g(x) = (f(x))^2$ is uniformly continuous. Prove or disprove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

According to me $f$ should be uniformly continuous but I am facing difficulty in proving that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider the function $h\colon [0,+\infty) \to [0,+\infty),\, h(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Note $f = h\circ g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f = h \circ g$, where $h:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$. Now:

- $g$ is uniformly continuous (the assumption).
- $h$ is uniformly continuous ([$\sqrt x$ is uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569928/sqrt-x-is-uniformly-continuous)).
- The composition of two uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous ([composition of two uniformly continuous functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575805/composition-of-two-uniformly-continuous-functions)).

  It follows that $f$ is uniformly continuous.